# Zend hydrator and underscore separated key

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'am looking for an option to hydrate my rows and keep only the value after the first underscore in order to get this :

Table :

```
user_id
user_name
```

Model

```
function getId()
function getName()
```

If I use the defaults paramaters my model functions are :

```
getUserId()
getUserName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your hydrator like this:

```
$hydrator = new Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(); //without passing false to constructor
```

`ClassMethods` has a property `$underscoreSeparatedKeys` which is `true` by default.